# Oracle View - Determine if dependant table of a view appears within a subquery

Tags: regex, oracle

This is a long shot I know but is it possible to determine if a particular table is referenced within a subquery in a view or block of code?

If the only solution is to use Regular Expressions on the text of the view/query block then can someone please provide a example of how this would be achieved?

For example, in the following query:

```
SELECT col1, the_name FROM 
( /* beginning of inline view */
SELECT col1,
       col2,
       col3, 
       (select name from table2 where id=2) the_name /* this is the subquery */
  FROM table1
) inline_view /* end of inline view */
```

I would like to detect that table2 has been referenced in the correlated subquery. However, **although table1 is between brackets and is an inline view, it is not a subquery and I wouldn't expect that to be matched.**

I hope my request makes sense...and hope even more that someone can help!

Thanks,

Tomás

Comment: Programming languages are one step above regular expressions in the [Chomsky Hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_grammar#The_hierarchy), so Regex cannot be used to effectively parse a programming language (though some have tried, and others will tell you it is possible using recursion in Regex, which gets very messy, very fast). For whatever programming language you're using (you didn't specify), you should find an effective SQL parser instead (or write a very very basic one yourself, they aren't too hard). **Or**, I know this is really basic, but can you just search for `table2`?

Comment: I think everybody is missing the distinction between a subquery and an inline view.  Your question is interesting and accurate, but you may want to add a warning in bold.

Answer (score 0):

Check dictionary view [USER_DEPENDENCIES](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_1066.htm#REFRN20053), there you should find it.

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_DEPENDENCIES 
WHERE REFERENCED_NAME = 'TABLE2' AND REFERENCED_TYPE IN ('TABLE','VIEW');
```

But it does not detect dynamic statements, e.g. this one is not discovered:

```
cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
OPNE cur FOR 'SELECT * FROM EMP';
...
```

Comment: This also will not tell if the table is used in a subquery instead of an inline view.  (It's a very tricky question.)

Comment: @jonearles Thanks again for highlighting my actual requirement. Perhaps I didn't make it clear enough about the subquery part. Maybe its a reflection on my question and I might need to revisit how it is posed!...

Answer (score -1):

Would this help?

```
SELECT   *
  FROM   all_source
 WHERE   text LIKE '%(%TABLE2%)%'
```

Comment: This will not distinguish between a subquery and an inline view.